# Walls dont appear to be bolted to foundation - any retrofix?

Tags: walls, foundation

After quick inspection of the walls in my house I dont think they are bolted to the foundation.
At least I couldnt find the bolts - I think there mightbe several concrete nails holding it in place but thats about it.

It's 2x4 walls on top of the 2x6 sill plate.

Will something like this hurricane ties be sufficient enough or do I really  need to properly bolt it down?

https://www.strongtie.com/foundationanchors_concreteconnectorsandanchors/ufp_plate/p/ufp

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CyHwF9j.jpg]

Comment: I have used the clips in the past to pass inspections on large remodels that were built pre 1920, all the homes after that time line in Ca & Or have had anchors.  Some of the really old homes have only had 2 anchors on a wall.  All stem walls should have anchors to keep the wall in place.

Comment: On a neat and workmanlike install you might not see the bolts unless you pry up the 2x4. 2x6 - washer, nut, bolt trimmed close to nut, pocket cut in 2x4 for nut and cut off bolt. Try hunting with a VERY strong magnet?

Comment: Yeah, normally the sill plate is bolted down, and the walls nailed down as any wall would be on a wooden deck.